# " mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db:3306' (-2 Name or service not known)"

Tags: python, mysql, docker, flask, docker-compose

I am running the docker composed flask and MySQL container but I am facing this error  " MySQL.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db:3306' (-2 Name or service not known)"

docker version : 20.10.7

please help me to resolve this

my project structure is:

```
flaskProject6/
├── app/
│   ├── app.py
│   |── Dockerfile
│   │── requirements.txt
│──db/
│   |── init.sql
├── docker-compose.yml
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==2.0.1
mysql_connector
```

app.py

```
from typing import List, Dict
from flask import Flask
import mysql.connector
import json

app = Flask(__name__)


def favorite_colors() -> List[Dict]:
    config = {

        'user': 'root',
        'password': 'root',
        'host':'db',
        'port': '3306',
        'database': 'knights'
    }
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM favorite_colors')
    results = [{name: color} for (name, color) in cursor]
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()

    return results


@app.route('/')
def index() -> str:
    return json.dumps({'favorite_colors': favorite_colors()})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Dockerfile

```
# Use an official Python runtime as an image
FROM python:3.9.4

# The EXPOSE instruction indicates the ports on which a container
# will listen for connections
# Since Flask apps listen to port 5000  by default, we expose it
EXPOSE 5000

# Sets the working directory for following COPY and CMD instructions
# Notice we haven’t created a directory by this name - this instruction
# creates a directory with this name if it doesn’t exist
WORKDIR /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
COPY requirements.txt /app

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# Run app.py when the container launches
COPY app.py /app
CMD python app.py
```

init.sql

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS knights;
use knights;

CREATE TABLE favorite_colors (
  name VARCHAR(20),
  color VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO favorite_colors
  (name, color)
VALUES
  ('Lancelot', 'blue'),
  ('Galahad', 'yellow');
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  app:
    build: ./app
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.26
    ports:
      - "32000:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: knights
    volumes:
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
    restart: always
```

output:
in Building step:

```
C:\Users\Karthik\Desktop\flaskProject6>docker-compose up --build
Creating network "flaskproject6_default" with the default driver
Building app
[+] Building 15.6s (10/10) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                          0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                             0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.9.4                                                                                              15.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                             0.2s
 => => transferring context: 63B                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.9.4@sha256:03ac9e7e04a401af550774bc974c03d02fd0e74c8a185f7ab902e1be99d1ec98                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [2/5] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [3/5] COPY requirements.txt /app                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [4/5] RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt                                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [5/5] COPY app.py /app                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                        0.2s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:3bf215f9a31f612a8d9c75ac845731ccda8654fc189f7ae2fce7baf7d4086403                                                                  0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/flaskproject6_app                                                                                                          0.0s
Creating flaskproject6_db_1 ... done
Creating flaskproject6_app_1 ... done
Attaching to flaskproject6_db_1, flaskproject6_app_1
db_1   | 2021-08-16 09:13:42+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.26-1debian10 started.
db_1   | 2021-08-16 09:13:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
db_1   | 2021-08-16 09:13:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.26-1debian10 started.
db_1   | 2021-08-16 09:13:43+00:00 [Warn] [Entrypoint]: MYSQL_PASSWORD specified, but missing MYSQL_USER; MYSQL_PASSWORD will be ignored
db_1   | 2021-08-16 09:13:43+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:13:43.466536Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.26) initializing of server in progress as process 44
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:13:43.520113Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
app_1  |  * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
app_1  |  * Environment: production
app_1  |    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
app_1  |    Use a production WSGI server instead.
app_1  |  * Debug mode: off
app_1  |  * Running on all addresses.
app_1  |    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
app_1  |  * Running on http://172.22.0.3:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:13:45.953897Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:13:49.561880Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:13:49.562474Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:13:49.794492Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initia
lize-insecure option.
db_1   | 2021-08-16 09:13:57+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
db_1   | 2021-08-16 09:13:57+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:13:57.883021Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.26) starting as process 93
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:13:57.913341Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:13:58.259382Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:13:59.028875Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:13:59.029924Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:13:59.046457Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:13:59.047374Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this
 channel.
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:13:59.061686Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible t
o all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:13:59.321041Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:13:59.322457Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.26'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.so
ck'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
db_1   | 2021-08-16 09:13:59+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
db_1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1   | 2021-08-16 09:14:09+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database knights
db_1   |
db_1   | 2021-08-16 09:14:09+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
db_1   |
db_1   |
db_1   | 2021-08-16 09:14:09+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:14:09.597391Z 12 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user root. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.26).
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:14:11.561783Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.26)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
db_1   | 2021-08-16 09:14:11+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped
db_1   |
db_1   | 2021-08-16 09:14:11+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
db_1   |
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:14:12.524304Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.26) starting as process 1
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:14:12.537075Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:14:12.946871Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:14:13.229828Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:14:13.230032Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:14:13.231501Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:14:13.231876Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this
 channel.
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:14:13.239435Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible t
o all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:14:13.261895Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx
.sock
db_1   | 2021-08-16T09:14:13.262051Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.26'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.so
ck'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

i also tried by using run

```
PS C:\Users\Karthik> docker run -p 8085:5000 flaskproject6_app
 * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on all addresses.
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
 * Running on http://172.17.0.2:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[2021-08-16 07:30:40,748] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 482, in open_connection
    addrinfos = socket.getaddrinfo(self.server_host,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 953, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/app/app.py", line 30, in index
    return json.dumps({'favorite_colors': favorite_colors()})
  File "/app/app.py", line 18, in favorite_colors
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 206, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 500, in open_connection
    raise errors.InterfaceError(
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db:3306' (-2 Name or service not known)
172.17.0.1 - - [16/Aug/2021 07:30:40] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: Maybe you can add   ` depends_on: db`, wait for the mysql container starting up , then start your flask container,  see also https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/

Comment: Thank you @frank_lee but I applied as u said it doesn't work for  my problem

Comment: Do you user `docker-compose up -d` to start your services? It's seems that you use `docker run`

Comment: no, I used docker-compose up --build  and I am suing version 3

Comment: how about add `restart: always`  to in your `app` in the `docker-compose.yml` ?

Comment: sorry @frank_lee again i am facing the same issue

Comment: As mentioned, don't use `docker run` like your question shows. Also remove `links` and replace it with `depends_on`. Please [edit] your question to include these changes and new issues you face

Comment: @KarthikKKashi maybe you can provide your `app.py` and `requirements.txt` so I can reproduce your problem

Comment: I added as u mentioned

Comment: Try change `mysql-connector` to `mysql-connector-python` in the `requirements.txt`, it works for me, I can see the color data by visiting `http://localhost:5000`

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution by changing the version of an image from 8.0.26 to mysql:5.6